Error in finding quartiles and outliers in R Studio
So I am doing a university project and I am trying to find outliers in a dataset with 722 rows and 9 columns so there are over 6000 variables.
I have been trying many ways:
Firstly with Z scores where this happened.
z_scores<-(concrete_strength_test-mean(concrete_strength_test))/sd(concrete_strength_test)
Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(concrete_strength_test) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

and secondly quantiles:
Q1 <- quantile(concrete_strength_test, .25)
Error in quantile.default(concrete_strength_test, 0.25) : 
  missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE

as there were missing or NA values I ran the code with the mice function and got rid of them but then I got this error:
Q1 <- quantile(concrete_strength_test_imputed, .25)
Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames

I'm just not sure where to go next so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames means concrete_strength_test_imputed is a data.frame but it should be a numeric vector. Use $ or unlist to access the dataframe's vectors. If possible please provide a minimal reproducible example to get more detailed info.

@AndreWildberg I don't believe that fully solves the problem as using unlist and then going through the code just results in the error: Error in data[outliers] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Thank you though. Also I'm not quite sure how to provide a minimal reproducible example

Try with e.g. dput(head(data, 10)).

Mabski, I think you should back up and look at why you are doing outlier detection. You have fewer than 1000 points in a 9 dimensional space -- it is likely that every one of them is "exceptional" along one dimension or another. (You might think about how many data points you would need to ensure that a 9 dimensional space is well-populated.) Also, "outlier detection" suggests there's something wrong with exceptional values. Are you sure about that? Bear in mind, often the most exceptional points are also the most interesting. My advice is to just omit the filtering altogether.

If I understand you correctly, you want to treat the 9 columns as one big bag of values and not find the quantiles and outliers in each column?
If this is the case, the data structure of concrete_strength_test is wrong. You have it as a data.frame/list but need it as a vector. To do this, convert it first. Then you can do all kinds of analyses:
values = c(as.matrix(concrete_strength_test))

z_scores = (values-mean(values))/sd(values)
q1 = quantile(values,c(.25),na.rm=T)

